# How to disable element on mobile devices on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I've got website: https://romeo24.live/ and there I've got a social plugin on the right top corner. On the desktop is ok, but I wanted to hide it on mobile devices. Should I make it with css? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is by using css Media query (@media) see  some documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add information on what you have already tried as well as a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could state that it is NSFW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) CSS at-rule for control style sheet in some screens (like mobile devices). In your site, you can use this CSS code for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#sfsi_floater {
  display: none;
  }
}
```